# restore deterministic wallet from specific date (YYYY-MM-DD) - Error: specified date is in the future

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, error-log

I am test restoring a Monero wallet.

```
./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet
```

At this point:

```
Restore from specific blockchain height (optional, default 0),
or alternatively from specific date (YYYY-MM-DD): 2017-04-21
Error: specified date is in the future
```

I chose to restore from 2017-04-21 onwards. 
Obviously this date is not in the future and if I ask my computer, what date it is:

```
user@hostname:~$ date
Mon May 29 12:28:20 CEST 2017
```

he agrees.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know now what the problem is:
monerod is still syncing and above date is "in the future" because monerod did not get until 2017-04-21 yet ...

Comment: Interesting. That should still work, please file on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues